# Trouble generating MD5 fingerprint with new keystore

Tags: android, eclipse, md5, keytool

I'm trying to generate the MD5 Fingerprint I will use with the release of my application. I used Eclipse to Compile and Sign my application, which gave me a keystore file and a .apk file. Now i need to generate the MD5 for my MapViews. I tried using the cmd prompt to generate it, but everytime it states that no such file exists. Is there somewhere special i need to be storing the keystore so the keytool has access to it? Also, once i get the MD5 fingerprint, all i have to do is insert it and re-compile and sign my application (the same way i previously did it). Am i correct on that assumption? I've read through the developer docs and I'm still unclear on the whole process. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default debug keystore automatically. For release, you need to generate your own private keystore first with something like:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias release_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Once you've chosen and entered all the passwords (make a note of them!) you've generated a new MD5 (different from the debug one)

To view it:

keytool -list -alias release_alias -keystore c:\YOUR PATH TO IT\my-release-key.keystore

gives:

release_alias, 08-Sep-2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): CE:xx:xx:xx etc....

If you use Google maps then you need a new API key for this. Repeat the process you did to generate the one for the debug MD5 but enter the new MD5

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, i accidentally downvoted your answer, if you edit your answer, i will be able to upvote.

Comment: No problem, I've made that mistake myself on a mobile phone! added a full stop to my answer.